Manual partitioning causes error
I tried to install Linux by console, starting with partitioning and so on.
I do the same steps again and again, but when the installer (Live-System) starts, it's crashing.
I don't know why, everything seems to be right.
Doing the settings by the graphical installer leads to a crash right after setting the lvm.
    sudo parted /dev/vda
    (parted) mktable gpt
    (parted) mkpart ESP fat32 1MiB 501MiB
    (parted) set 1 boot on
    (parted) set 1 esp on
    (parted) mkpart primary ext4 501MiB 1001MiB
    (parted) mkpart primary 1001MiB 100%


    sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/vda3
    sudo cryptsetup open /dev/vda3 cryptlvm


    sudo pvcreate /dev/mapper/cryptlvm
    sudo vgcreate ubunut-vg /dev/mapper/cryptlvm
    sudo lvcreate -L 20G -n root ubuntu-vg
    sudo lvcreate -L 100G -n home ubunut-vg
    sudo lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n swap ubunut-vg


    sudo mkswap /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap
    sudo mkfs.btrfs /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
    sudo mkfs.btrfs /dev/ubuntu-vg/home

    sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/vda1
    sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/vda2


    sudo mkdir /mnt/home
    sudo mount /dev/ubuntu-vg/home /mnt/home
    sudo mount /dev/ubuntu-vg/root /mnt
    sudo swapon /dev/ubunut-vg/swap

    sudo mkdir /mnt/boot
    sudo mount /dev/vda2 /mnt/boot

    sudo mkdir /mnt/boot/efi
    sudo mount /dev/vda1 /mnt/boot/efi

What's wrong with this config?

Ubuntu 24.04 desktop installer does not like pre-existing filesystem/lvm/luks/etc. not sure what other issues there might be with it. You can try with older Ubuntu LTS release, then upgrade. If that 500M partition is meant to be /boot, it might be too small. Your mount order (/mnt/home first, then /mnt) might cause /mnt/home/ to be invisible, usually you mount / first then /home on top of it, not the other way around...

If the above comments lead you to a solution, please post an answer (which you can self-accept after 48 hrs to gain valuable reputation points).

is ubunut-vg on vgcreate line a copy/paste typo ?
